# strange behavior when trying to re-render data inside slot in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

I am getting strange behaviour when trying to dynamically update the content of a slot in Vue with Vuetify. I'm sure this is just a function of misunderstanding how slots work.

I have a slot in a custom component, like so:

```
<template #selectButtons="slotProps">
      <v-icon @click="dropToggle(slotProps.player)"    
         :color="dropColor(slotProps.player)"
         class="mr-5"
       >
         fas fa-skull-crossbones
       </v-icon>
</template>
```

When the user clicks on the icon, it is meant to toggle the icon to different colors.

I cannot seem to get `dropColor` to fire on each click consistently, HOWEVER, the weird part is, if I make some change inside the `<v-icon>` component, like say I just add `{{dropColor(slotProps.player)}}` inside the `v-icon` tags, then all of a sudden the code will work.

But then if I do a full refresh of the page, it stops working. Then I delete that code and put it back in, then it works again!

I have tried forceUpdate and keys on the v-icon tag.

Would appreciate any help

Comment: Could you post the code for `dropToggle`?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass function `dropColor(slotProps.player)` as props. The better idea is to replace function to an object or variable and change that object/variable within method `dropToggle(slotProps.player)` after `@click` event is firing .